# Subsetting a column

Tags: r

I have a data frame(data10) with 128 obs and 46 variables, I am interested in isolating a single column(variable) based on a condition(trial). I wonder why I am getting 'incorrect number of dimensions' in my R console. Please find my code below.

```
PrePost_NJ <-data10$NormalizedJerk[data10$trial=="102",]
```

I need some education, ​please

Answer (score 0):

Every time you ask a question try to include some data so people can play with in order to find correct answers.
In this case, you shouldn't use a "," in the brackets:

```
PrePost_NJ <-data10$NormalizedJerk[data10$trial=="102"]
```

Take a look to the 'tidyverse' package, it will make your data manipulation easier.